# How can the result of print-like formatting be used in a gdb printf expression?

Tags: gdb

In GDB I can get nice formatting of a POD struct when I use a plain print command:

```
(gdb) print l[0] 
$9 = {rq = 10, eq = 0 }
```

I would like to use a printf expression in a gdb user-defined function that formats this variable in the same way.

What is the correct syntax to do this?  The "natural" way to do this fails

```
(gdb) printf "%s", l[0]
Value can't be converted to integer.
```

Comment: I don't think `printf` can do that. Why don't you just use `print` or `output`?

Comment: @ssbssa The actual printf format string I want to use in the function is significantly more complicated and includes many other variables.  This is just a minimal example of what I want to do.

Comment: But what's the reason why it has to be done with the `printf` command?

Comment: @ssbssa Any mechanism that lets me do the equivalent of printing output in the format I want is acceptable.  I am not familiar with the 'output' command, but looking at the gdb manual I don't think 'print' takes format strings and multiple variables.  It's just printf is built to do this.  This might be an XY problem.

Comment: I've added an answer, but you can also get what you want by going with @ssbssa's suggestion and using a series of `printf` and `output` commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been a few questions where the answer involves putting the output of a GDB command into a convenience variable. Rather than writing Python every time, as in my [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75818751/2554472), here's a convenience function named `$execute` that does this. You can put it in the file `~/execute.py`, and load it into GDB using the `source` command.

```py
import gdb

class Execute(gdb.Function):
  """Execute the first argument as a command.
Returns a string (C array of char).
Optional second argument chomp=True will remove trailing newlines.
In general, the first argument should be a C string,
and the second argument a C bool."""

  def __init__(self):
    super(Execute, self).__init__("execute")

  def invoke(self, arg, chomp=True):
    ret = gdb.execute(arg.string(), to_string=True)
    if chomp:
       ret = ret.rstrip('\n')
    return ret

Execute()
```

And here's how to use it in your case:

```
(gdb) source ~/execute.py
(gdb) set $firstelt = $execute("output l[0]")
(gdb) printf "In thread %d, first element is %s.\n", $_thread, $firstelt
In thread 1, first element is {rq = 10, eq = 0}.
```

The GDB `output` command does the same thing as `print`, but it omits the `$n =`  at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Using GDB's Python extension, you can run any GDB command and put its output into a convenience variable, whose type will be an array of characters. You can then use this convenience variable in a `printf` command with the `%s` format.

```
(gdb) python gdb.set_convenience_variable("firstelt",gdb.execute("output l[0]",to_string=True))
(gdb) ptype $firstelt
type = char [17]
(gdb) printf "In thread %d, first element is %s.\n", $_thread, $firstelt
In thread 1, first element is {rq = 10, eq = 0}.
```

I used the `output` command here, which is just like `print`, but it omits the `$n =` at the beginning and the newline at the end.